# Changing UIDatePicker Size in IOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm using `UIDatePicker` in my app.

In iOS 5 I can change the width and height of the `UIDatePicker`, however in iOS 6 I cannot. I am using the following code:

```
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 90, 100, 100);
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

Is there anything extra I have to do for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [different size for DatePicker objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138101/different-size-for-datepicker-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIDatePicker` displays a `UIPickerView`. Unfortunately, a `UIPickerView`'s size cannot be changed.

Sure, you could try to trick it by using transforms, but please don't. Not only will it be a headache to you, it'll be harder to use, ugly, fuzzy, and go against human interface guidelines (by making touch targets too small).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i did change in IOS 5 can't I change in IOS 6?